# Regex with multiple possible patterns

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm looking to match multiple patterns (ptrn) that match either ZABCY, ZACDY, or ZEFGY within "data". I wrote the code below, but my "output" is empty. I expect to have expected_output. Where am I going wrong?

```
require(stringr)
data <- "ZABCYDZEFGYHZY"
ptrn <- "Z[ABC|ACD|EFG]Y"
output <- data.frame(str_locate_all(data, ptrn))
expected.output <- data.frame(2, 4)
```

Comment: It is a very common typo, `[...]` is a character class that matches a set of chars or char ranges. Use a grouping construct, `(...)` or `(?:...)` (non-capturing group).

Comment: I'm not sure how `(?:)` works in general (I'm actually not super-expert with regexes), but `ptrn <- "(?:Z)(ABC|ACD|EFG)(?:Y)"` does *not* seem to ignore as expected (i.e. using this pattern the first hit is recorded as going from position 1 to 5, not 2 to 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need

```
ptrn <- "Z(ABC|ACD|EFG)Y"
```

(square brackets `[]` refer to character sets; the `()` protects your `ABC` alternative from being read as `ZABC`, and similarly for `EFGY`)

However, I'm a little confused about your expected output.  I get

```
  start end
1     1   5
2     7  11
```

Using look-ahead and look-behind expressions for the `Z` and `Y` might be what you have in mind:

```
ptrn <- "(?<=Z)(ABC|ACD|EFG)(?=Y)"
```

this matches the `Z` and `Y` but doesn't include them when evaluating the hit location, so the first hit is given as (2,4), which may be what you want

Pointed out in the comments that if you wanted to use lookahead/lookbehind (`(?...)` stuff) with base R functions (`gsub()`, `grep()`, `grepl()` etc.), then you'd have to specify `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: any particular reason for the downvote ...?  Should I use `(?:Z)` instead of `(?<=Z)` ?

Comment: You’ll need to use `perl = TRUE` to use look-behind or look-ahead expressions if using base R regex functions. Just realised you’re not though, so ignore me.